# How to get SMTP address for exchange user quickly?

Tags: c#, email, outlook

The below is my code, the PrimarySmtpAddress use 50ms which need more than 15 s to load more 300 users. I am not familiar with Outlook API, and it seems this Property is the usual way to retrieve the SMTP address, but it is far too slow.

Is there other way to retrieve the SMTP address or I use this property incorrectly?

The .NetFramework is 3.5

Outlook Version is 2010

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook is 12.0.0.0

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNS = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
olNS.Logon(null, null, false, true);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressLists als = olNS.AddressLists;
if (als == null) return;
Stopwatch watcher = new Stopwatch();
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressList addrList in als)
{
    if (addrList.Name == "Global Contact Address" || addrList.Name == "Global Address List")
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry entry in addrList.AddressEntries)
        {
            if (entry == null) continue;
            if (entry.Name == null || entry.Name.Trim() == "") continue;
            if (entry.Address == null || entry.Address.Trim() == "") continue;

            eMailInfo info = new eMailInfo();
            info.Name = entry.Name;
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            watcher.Start();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser user = entry.GetExchangeUser();
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("This get exchange user time {0}", watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            watcher.Reset();
            if (user != null)
            {
                watcher.Start();
                info.Address = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("This get exchange user address time {0}", watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds));
                watcher.Reset();
            }
            else
                info.Address = entry.Address;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to retrieve SMTP addresses for all GAL users?

Comment: Yes, I need to make a outlook contact list like component, and the OutLook can show the SMTP addresses quickly, so I wonder is there any way to implement this.

Comment: Note that Outlook never retrieves all items from any particular list - it reads 20 or so entries necessary to show the current page, the rest is retrieved on demand as you scroll. It also uses IMAPITable to retrieve multiple rows in a single call. OOM does not expose that functionality. it is either Extended MAPI or Redemption (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Check if these helps

- [Account Object(Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869974.aspx)   Look for `Outlook.OlAccountType.olExchange` in the example provided.
- [Obtain Information for Multiple Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868554.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to retrieve `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) from multiple GAL entries in a single call - use `AddressEntires.MAPITable` property to retrieve the [IMAPITable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapitableiunknown) MAPI interface. You can then use `IMAPITable::SetColumns / QueryRows` or `HrQueryAllRows` to retrieve the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property from multiple entries in a single call.

If Extended MAPI in C++/Delphi is not an option, you can try [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [MAPITable](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm) object (`ExecSQL` method). It retrieves all SMTP addresses in a single call without opening opening each and every GAL object, so it will be at least an order of magnitude faster, maybe two order faster.

```
Redemption.MAPITable table = new Redemption.MAPITable();
table.Item = addrList.AddressEntries
ADODB.Recordset recordset = table.ExecSQL("SELECT \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F\" from list")
while (!recordset.EOF)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(recordset.Fields[0].Value)
  recordset.MoveNext
}
```