# Global Address list using Outlook Redemption

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I am using GetAddressList to access  Address List as given here:
https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238320-session-addressbook-doesnt-find-my-address-lists

But it take more time if there are 500 or more users.
Is there any fastest method to retrieve  Address List.
How can I retrieve  Address List using Redemption.MAPITable object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RDOAddressList.AddressEntries.MAPITable`.
You can create an instance of the `RDOSession` object, set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` from OOM, then retrieve `RDOAddressList` using either `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` or `RDOSession.GetAddressListFromID.`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for reply. I am try as you explain at following link:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590083/how-to-get-smtp-address-for-exchange-user-quickly    ADODB.Recordset recordset = table.ExecSQL("SELECT \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F\" from list"); but ADODB is undefined. How can I use ADODB.Recordset in my vc++ application so I could retrieve Name and SMTPAddress  from Global address List using MAPI table.

Comment: Did you import the ADODB type library into your VC++ app? It is not any different from importing Outlook or Redemption type libraries.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.   I try using this method but not sucess                                           #import "msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "adoEOF")
_bstr_t valField1;      
_RecordsetPtr pRstAuthors = NULL;      
pRstAuthors = table.ExecSQL(_T("SELECT \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F\" from list"));
while (!pRstAuthors->adoEOF){
valField1 = pRstAuthors->Fields->GetItem("Name")->Value;
pRstAuthors->MoveNext();}